# Missing letters in @font-face font on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face, letters

I have very strange problem about `@font-face` font **Proxima Nova Bold** (Polish letters) which I bought in shop. I tested it on different browsers and systems and my two friends which has got Firefox and Windows 7 has got missing letters.

I found solution with disabling ligatures, but it doesn't work because we can see that there are single letters missing, for example T, A or 3. 
Example:

[image]

Can it be technical problem with font, should I ask fontspring? Or can I repair it by CSS? It is quite difficult to test because I don't have access to computers which has got that situation and not every Firefox on Windows 7 has got that bug. This is problem with font because when we changed in inspector to Arial everything was good.

It can be not connected but the same person who has got missing letters on firefox has got all letters missing on Chrome 37 with Direct Write enabled. When we disabled Direct Write letters were shown.

This is how I load it in CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNova-Bold';
    src: url('assets/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('assets/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('assets/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('assets/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('assets/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold-webfont.svg#proxima_nova_rgbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I have the identical problem

Comment: As far as I remember, it was a problem with font itself. Then I bought Proxima Nova from a shop and it was okay.

Comment: Yes, I found the issue too, fontspring sells the font without the extra glyphs and you have to choose the languages in a dropdown and re-download the fonts. Eventually I got my hands on the latin extreme version and it had all the languages supported in file. Thanks so much for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I used this exact font on a project recently and did not experience any issues with it across a wide variety of browsers. Try generating the font yourself from the original file for a sanity check.

You should not and most likely will not be able to resolve using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the file again and serving it again. Sometimes your file could have been corrupted.

Comment: Of course I tried, but it didn't help. Maybe converting from the base .otf to other types with special converter will help.